# Ubuntu 22.04.1 installer cannot detect dual identical NVMe devices

Tags: system-installation, multipath

My machine has 2 identical NVMe storage devices:

```
$ sudo dmesg  | grep -i nvme
[    1.920305] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:04:00.0
[    1.957490] nvme nvme0: allocated 64 MiB host memory buffer.
[    1.990803] nvme nvme0: 15/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    2.024382] nvme nvme1: pci function 0000:b4:00.0
[    2.057384] nvme nvme1: allocated 64 MiB host memory buffer.
[    2.089470] nvme nvme1: 15/0/0 default/read/poll queues
```

When I first launch the Ubuntu live installer, both the NVMe storage devices is identified as a multipath device:

```
$ lsblk
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
...
sda        8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
sdb        8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
sdc        8:32   1  14.4G  0 disk
└─sdc1     8:33   1  14.4G  0 part
nvme0n1  259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
└─mpatha 253:0    0 931.5G  0 mpath
nvme1n1  259:1    0 931.5G  0 disk
└─mpatha 253:0    0 931.5G  0 mpath

$ sudo multipath -ll
mpatha (eui.00000000000000000000010000000000) dm-0 NVME,HP SSD EX900 1TB
size=932G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=active
| `- 0:1:1:1 nvme0n1 259:0 active ready running
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 1:1:1:1 nvme1n1 259:1 active ready running
```

I try to remove the multipath devices:

```
$ sudo multipath -F
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
...
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
sdb       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
sdc       8:32   1  14.4G  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   1  14.4G  0 part
nvme0n1 259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
nvme1n1 259:1    0 931.5G  0 disk
```

Back to installer, after refresh the multipath device is gone but it still can't detect the individual NVMe devices.

I would like to install the ubuntu in one of the NVMe device but I have no way to proceed with my current machine configuration.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: I am using `ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso`

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem and followed the exact same path you did and landed in the same dead-end: the "smart" partition tool stubbornly refuses to see the two devices.

The only solution I found was to use the old text based alternate install, which does indeed see the devices.

Unfortunately, I don't know if that old-style installer can be used to install 22.04 :(